# How and where do I send a GET request from an HTML form in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I making a page in Wordpress and I need to be able to use the data submitted by an HTML form as variables. The form in my case is two simple dropdown select forms with a submit button. I am not sure what to put as the action attribute for the form and how to access it. I want to use the GET method to do this, but I am not sure how to use PHP in Wordpress or where I would store a PHP page/file. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the HTML code of my page, the items in square brackets are from plugins. kids.php is a file on my computer that I ran it locally with, it has nothing to do with my Wordpress site and does not do anything there.

```
<form id="form" action="kids.php" method="get">
[one_half]

    <h3>Select a Country</h3>
        <div class="dropdown">      
            <select id="dropdownl" name=dropdownl>
                <option disabled="true">Country</option>
                <option disabled="true">North America</option>
                                <option value="62292">Canada</option>
                <option value="72808">Mexico</option>
                <option value="144586">Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="163668">United States</option>
                                <option disabled="true">South America</option>
                <option value="63839">Argentina</option>
                <option value="67922">Brazil</option>
                <option value="78702">Colombia</option>
                <option value="60670">Peru</option>
                                <option disabled="true">Oceania</option>
                <option value="32137">Australia & New Zealand</option>
                                <option disabled="true">Africa</option>
                <option value="63210">Egypt</option>
                <option value="78700">South Africa</option>
                                <option disabled="true">Asia</option>
                <option value="66137">China</option>
                <option value="49932">India</option>
                <option value="40308">Israel</option>
                <option value="78709">Japan</option>
                <option value="223252">Philippines</option>
                <option value="60438">Republic of Korea</option>
                <option value="69605">Singapore</option>
                <option value="70391">Taiwan</option>
                <option value="71971">Thailand</option>
                                <option disabled="true">Europe</option>
                <option value="32142">Austria</option>
                <option value="32146">Belgium</option>
                <option value="78707">Bulgaria</option>
                <option value="72763">Czech Republic</option>
                <option value="31277">Denmark</option>
                <option value="62393">Finland</option>
                <option value="31223">France</option>
                <option value="31026">Germany</option>
                <option value="63208">Greece</option>
                <option value="63016">Hungary</option>
                <option value="183519">Ireland</option>
                <option value="122492">Italy</option>
                <option value="142792">Lithuania</option>
                <option value="162411">Netherlands</option>
                <option value="67164">Norway</option>
                <option value="56320">Poland</option>
                <option value="62344">Portugal</option>
                <option value="67210">Romania</option>
                <option value="68895">Russian Federation</option>
                <option value="143380">Serbia</option>
                <option value="78705">Slovakia</option>
                <option value="25372">Spain</option>
                <option value="25520">Sweden</option>
                <option value="25408">Switzerland</option>
                <option value="67375">Turkey</option>
                <option value="63212">Ukraine</option>
                <option value="25482">United Kingdom</option>
            </select>   
        </div> 

[/one_half]



[one_half_last]

<h3>Select a Country</h3>
    <div class="dropdown">

        <select id="dropdownr" name=dropdownr>
                <option disabled="true">Country</option>
                <option disabled="true">North America</option>
                                <option value="62292">Canada</option>
                <option value="72808">Mexico</option>
                <option value="144586">Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="163668">United States</option>
                                <option disabled="true">South America</option>
                <option value="63839">Argentina</option>
                <option value="67922">Brazil</option>
                <option value="78702">Colombia</option>
                <option value="60670">Peru</option>
                                <option disabled="true">Oceania</option>
                <option value="32137">Australia & New Zealand</option>
                                <option disabled="true">Africa</option>
                <option value="63210">Egypt</option>
                <option value="78700">South Africa</option>
                                <option disabled="true">Asia</option>
                <option value="66137">China</option>
                <option value="49932">India</option>
                <option value="40308">Israel</option>
                <option value="78709">Japan</option>
                <option value="223252">Philippines</option>
                <option value="60438">Republic of Korea</option>
                <option value="69605">Singapore</option>
                <option value="70391">Taiwan</option>
                <option value="71971">Thailand</option>
                                <option disabled="true">Europe</option>
                <option value="32142">Austria</option>
                <option value="32146">Belgium</option>
                <option value="78707">Bulgaria</option>
                <option value="72763">Czech Republic</option>
                <option value="31277">Denmark</option>
                <option value="62393">Finland</option>
                <option value="31223">France</option>
                <option value="31026">Germany</option>
                <option value="63208">Greece</option>
                <option value="63016">Hungary</option>
                <option value="183519">Ireland</option>
                <option value="122492">Italy</option>
                <option value="142792">Lithuania</option>
                <option value="162411">Netherlands</option>
                <option value="67164">Norway</option>
                <option value="56320">Poland</option>
                <option value="62344">Portugal</option>
                <option value="67210">Romania</option>
                <option value="68895">Russian Federation</option>
                <option value="143380">Serbia</option>
                <option value="78705">Slovakia</option>
                <option value="25372">Spain</option>
                <option value="25520">Sweden</option>
                <option value="25408">Switzerland</option>
                <option value="67375">Turkey</option>
                <option value="63212">Ukraine</option>
                <option value="25482">United Kingdom</option>
        </select> 

    </div> 

[/one_half_last]
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to integrate your custom form in Wordpress, you have to do the following:

Create a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) by creating a new php file in your theme and include this convention on the top of the page:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example name */ ?>
```

You can include your form on this template file, but ensure that you leave the action attribute empty. Do not use common names for the input fields in your form, because you can easily make a conflict with some of WordPress' reserved names.

```
<form id="form" action="" method="get">
```

You can access the $_GET variable in this file or through the ["init" action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init).

Make sure to create a new Page from the WordPress dashboard and use your newly created custom template with this page. This way you can access your form on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the PHP page would need to be the action. If the page containing your form is the same page where the PHP script will execute, then you would use that path as the action.
So lets say your application runs on `example.com/subdir/mypage.php`, then your action could simply look like this: `action="/subdir/mypage.php"`
But if your PHP script runs in a different location, then your action would have to point to that location.

To access the parameters submitted from the form, your PHP script would need something like this:

```
<?php
$myvar=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
parse_str($myvar,$output);
$dropdownl_val=$output['dropdownl'];
$dropdownr_val=$output['dropdownr'];
?>
```

I would recommend you look into Wordpress plugin development though, because adding any scripts to your template means it would execute on every request, and that is not a good idea unless it is exactly what you want to achieve, or unless the page runs independently from your Wordpress application.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Where do I store a php file in Wordpress?

Comment: If you have some sort of file manager provided by your host or perhaps FTP access, you would be able to store files on the server like that, but I would recommend using the page on which your HTML is. A PHP file can contain regular HTML, while everything inside the `<?php ?>` tag must be PHP since that executes server-side. If your page has a .html extension, you can change it to .php and put PHP scripts in there.

Comment: If you are editing your wordpress template, then I believe you may not be able to add PHP script in there because it would sanitize it, and in that case I would recommend you look into developing plugins for wordpress since that should give you more control in a worpress application environment. That is actually the way to go, but would require a bit of learning.